# XAML designer System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I almost getting crazy, because getting message from XAML designer and do not know what to do
[image]

As you can see on the line

```
Could not load type 'Mocks.Libraries_Collection_Classes_Storages_0_229157595
```

there is a class called Storages in the Libraries.Collection namespace. When I remove the reference Libraries.Collection from current project like:
[image]

Then the xaml designer is working

[image]

And when I add the Libraries.Collection library again:
[image]
and open the XAML Designer, then the error appears again:
[image]

The class storages class looks like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Libraries.Collection.Classes
{
    public class Storages : ObservableCollection<Storage>
    {
        public Storages()
        {
        }

        public Storages(IEnumerable<Storage> coll) : base(coll)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using VS2015.
**Update**
I used fuslogvw.exe for record logs and the output looks as follow:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (12/8/2015 @ 8:05:42 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\XDesProc.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = XamlDesignerFaultInjection
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: XamlDesignerFaultInjection | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = XDesProc.exe
Calling assembly : Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\XDesProc.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/XamlDesignerFaultInjection/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/XamlDesignerFaultInjection/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/XamlDesignerFaultInjection/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/XamlDesignerFaultInjection/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/XamlDesignerFaultInjection/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/XamlDesignerFaultInjection/XamlDesignerFaultInjection.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

The problem is the xaml designer. What should I do as next step?

Answer (score 0):

After double reading your question I have edited this answer. 
In an older VS versions I faced this similar exception once, but with the difference that it was at runtime. In my case it end up being that a version of the assembly was already in the GAC. For determining the cause I used [Fuslogvw tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx), it could be your best change for you right now to see what is going on in your box.

Comment: First of all, thanks for advise. I did record the log, please take a look above and could you maybe tell me what is wrong.

Comment: First, make sure that the dll from your assembly is copied to the output path, specifically verify that Copy Local property for the reference is set to true. Also make sure that it is compiled against a compatible platform than your project(32, 64 bits,  or Any CPU).